# create binary entry in registry programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, registry, dcom

I'm automating setting dcom properties of an app programmatically in c#. When I manually change the setting thru component services I see the following entry in registry. But I need to do it programmatically.
This is what I did to create this entry in the registry:

1. Open Component Services -> Dcom -> locate the app
2. right click and properties -> security tab -> Launch and Activation Permissions -> Custom 
   -> Edit and added BuiltIn\IIS_IUSRs

Here is the result:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{0B902D3B-6517-4EBD-B61B-6F5830A77578}]
@="TestClient.AccBkrcn"
"LaunchPermission"=hex:01,00,04,80,74,00,00,00,84,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,\
  00,00,02,00,60,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,1f,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  05,12,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,1f,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,\
  20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,38,\
  02,00,00,00,00,14,00,1f,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,04,00,00,00,01,02,\
  00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
  00,20,02,00,00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) methods, especially `SetValue` to perform this task. Using the `SetValue` method, arrays of Byte[] are automatically stored as binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to write the value above to the registry using C#, you can use the `RegistryKey` class in the [Microsoft.Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.aspx) namespace:

```
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{0B902D3B-6517-4EBD-B61B-6F5830A77578", true);
    key.SetValue("TestClient.AccBkrcn", new byte[] { 01,00,04,80,74,00,00,00,84,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,
  00,00,02,00,60,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,1f,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,
  05,12,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,1f,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,
  20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,38,
  02,00,00,00,00,14,00,1f,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,04,00,00,00,01,02,
  00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,
  00,20,02,00,00 });
```

**EDIT:**

As Brent points out, you'll need to prefix each number with 0x or this won't work.

Comment: This code won't compile because the hexadecimal literals are not being preceded by 0x. Most of the literals that are valid are being interpreted as octal numbers, because they have leading zeroes. See http://goo.gl/f3xQ2 for integer literal syntax.